# One column of vertical text on draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I want to create a box with text in vertical, but I don't want characters to be rotated, I want them to be horizontal, just one on each line.
Like this:

[image: objective]

If you select vertical text all you get is rotated text, which is not what I want.

Comment: A new member has provided a solution that works: [Flying Ace's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173456). Consider changing your accepted answer and/or upvoting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the moment, draw.io doesn't support that but feel free to vote and track this feature request here:
https://trello.com/c/YmcXSJ61/382-insert-vertical-text-one-letter-on-top-of-the-next

Regards,

Comment: This link is broken, and archive.org doesn't seem to work for me to get a cached version.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click the HTML button <sup>**<kbd></></kbd>**</sup>  in the **Text** parameters:
   [image: Screenshot of the text 'My Assignments' next to the Text parameters dialog box and an arrow pointing to the HTML button]
2. Place your text 'My Assignments' inside a font tag that specifies the 'writing-mode' and 'text-orientation' styles as follows:

   ```
   <font style="writing-mode: vertical-rl; text-orientation: upright">My Assignments</font>
   ```

   [image: The code <font style="writing-mode: vertical-rl; text-orientation: upright">My Assignments</font> beside the resulting vertical text]

##### Note

- You can apply additional styles (eg. font-size, font-weight, face, alignment, etc.) in the same way as above, but if you simply use the available **Text** parameter options, Draw.io will automatically add/merge the necessary HTML with your existing style.
- For example, in the animation below, the font-size was set to 23 using the GUI  options and Draw.io automatically merged that style with the custom `writing-mode` and `text-orientation` styles that were already manually entered:
  [image: Example of changing the font size using the buttons in the Text parameters and then seeing that the HTML was updated automatically]